# Why is the output always 0.0?

Tags: java

```
//creates SevenTally class
public class SevenTally{

    private int count;

    public SevenTally(int diceCount){
        this.count = diceCount;
    }

    //creates experiment method
    public boolean experiment(){
        int winCount = 0;
        //creates array of dice rolled according to input
        int[] diceRolls = new int[count];
        //assigns random value from 1 to 6 to each array value
        for(int x = 0; x < diceRolls.length; x++) {
            diceRolls[x] = (1 + (int)(6 * Math.random()));
            for(int n = 0; n < diceRolls.length; n++) {
                for(int m = n + 1; m < n; m++){
                    //checks for two dice in the total rolls that sum to 7
                    if (diceRolls[n] + diceRolls[m] == 7)
                        winCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (winCount > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

It seems like the problem is with the array for loop. I tested just that section of the code and it was properly inputting values into my array but when I put the whole thing together, I think the array is left empty or empties after exiting the loop.

This is the class driver:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SevenDriver{    

    public static void main(String[] args){      
        System.out.println("Enter number of dice to toss");     
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);      
        int diceCount = s.nextInt(); 
        SevenTally t = new SevenTally(diceCount);
        int experiments = 1000000;
        int wins = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < experiments; j++)
            if(t.experiment()) wins++;

        System.out.println((double)wins/experiments);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are not explaining what you are trying to do, you simply ask people why the output was wrong. please add an explanation of the algorithm, and the expected results with some kind of test scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote

```
for(int m = n + 1; m < n; m++)
```

When `m` starts at `n+1`, and the loop should run while `m<n`, then there's not much to do. This one should work:

```
for(int m = n + 1; m < diceRolls.length; m++)
```